# Is there a publicly available compiler for OpenQasm3?

Tags: qiskit, programming

Today (Nov 2023) using OpenQasm3 in the IBM ecosystem can only be done by exporting OpenQasm3 programs to python QuantumCircuit object via qiskit.qasm3.load and qiskit.qasm3.loads or by exporting Qiskit code to OpenQasm3 via qiskit.qasm3.dump and qiskit.qasm3.dumps. Since OpenQasm3 is in principle an intermediate representation for quantum code, it must be compiled at some point into a code which is closer to the qubits and/or FPGAs in the case of classical fragments of OpenQasm3 code.

I have looked but could not find any information about this process. How is OpenQasm3 code processed on quantum devices? Does such code exist that is available to the public? If the code is not public, is there information about the process of compiling OpenQasm3 on the web besides the OpenQasm3 paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.14722.pdf?